# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_moment__ is not a function - tests fail with today's moment release

Tags: angular, webpack

Just performed an npm update and a new version of moment (for Angular) came in (version 2.19.0).

Now I get this error message when one of my tests run, I get this error.  I am also using WebPack so perhaps some incompatibility has been introduced?

Comment: We are running the latest version of webpack 3.6.0

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1974

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the grouping (* as) from the import statement. This works for me.

import moment from 'moment';

Comment: I experienced the same issue today. Downgrading the moment version (temporarily) to 2.18.1 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue as well with the latest moment release while using in Typescript/Aurelia/Webpack.

I switched my imports to:
`import moment from 'moment';`

and created a moment.d.ts until they fix the official one:

`declare module "moment" {
      export default any;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

to:

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';
```